# Is there an alternative for hadoop -getmerge?

Tags: hadoop, merge, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I was trying to merge 80 GB files in a cluster using hadoop get merge ,

but as hadoop get merge has the property of copying the files from hdfs to local file system i have to copy to local and then copyFromLocal to hdfs again ,

> hadoop fs -**getmerge** hdfs:///path_in_hdfs/* ./local_path
>
> hadoop fs **-copyFromLocal** ./local_path hdfs://Destination_hdfs_Path/

My problem here is The datanode local is less than 80 GB,

I need to know is there an alternative to -getmerge where merge happens directly from HDFS to HDFS

I tried hadoop -cat also but it is not working..

Answer (score 2):

HDFS command with `-cat` option should work. Pipe the result of `-cat` command to the `-put` command.

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://input_hdfs_path/* | hadoop fs -put - hdfs://output_hdfs_path/output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not a real alternative. You can achieve the same result via a MapReduce or Spark job (setting the parallelism for the output to 1), but there is not a solution using pure hdfs commands.

Comment: mark91 , can you help me how to achieve this using mapreduce code ,

Comment: you just need to run a Hadoop streaming job with the proper settings for input and output locations, input and output format and use 1 as number of reducers and IdentityMapper and IdentityReducer respectuively as mapper and reducer classes (here youcan find some docs: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html)

Answer (score 0):

Streaming may help. However the merged file will be in the sorted order (text before the first tab will be the key). If sorting is not desirable then streaming is not an option.

#### File 1

```
Tom     25
Pete    30
Kevin   26
```

#### File 2

```
Neil    28
Chris   31
Joe     27
```

#### Merged File

```
Chris   31
Joe     27
Kevin   26
Neil    28
Pete    30
Tom     25
```